# rails can't find nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Rails 5.  I have a feedback form that takes in a nested resource (receiver).

```
class Feedback < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :receiver_id
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :receiver
end

class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController
   def create
      begin
        @feedback = Feedback.new feedback_params
      rescue Exception => e
        binding.pry
      end
      ... do other stuff
   end

   def feedback_params
      params.require(:feedback).permit(:message, receiver_attributes: [:id, :email, :handle])
       end
   end
end

= f.fields_for :receiver do |r|
  = f.text_field :id, value: f.object.receiver.id, class: 'hidden'
```

my tests fail when it tries to create the feedback saying

```
#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with ID=980191240 for Feedback with ID=>
```

using the binding.pry, I can find the user with the test id

```
User.find 980191240
#<User id: 980191240, email: "wong.amy@example.com", created_at: "2018-03-27 02:50:52", updated_at: "2018-03-27 02:50:52", first_name: "amy", last_name: "wong", handle: "wong">
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: When you run `User.find 980191240`, what was your ENV ?

Comment: the binding.pry is being run in test, when I enter `Rails.env` into the pry console, I get "test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is with variable used on view, In your case for `receiver.id` you should use variable `r` instead of `f`

```
= f.fields_for :receiver do |r|
  = r.text_field :id, value: f.object.receiver.id, class: 'hidden'
```

also check correct params are passed not while creating feedback

Hope this will help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: I bet you're right.  good catch.  I'll try and check it tonight